# How to change the display pictures in userform depend on textbox 1 value

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have an Excel database of parts and I have created a userform where all the information about the parts will show up in the userform once I key in the part no in textbox1. 
But now I'm stucked where I need the picture of the part to show up as well once I key in the part no in textbox1.

Need some help.

Please refer below for the picture of my datebase and userform and also my codes to pull up the information.

Thanks.

Database:
[image: database]

Userform:
[image: userform]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ClearForm
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    GetData
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub         

Sub GetData()
    Dim id As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean
    If IsNumeric(UserForm1.TextBox1.Value) Then
        flag = False
        i = 0
        id = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value

        Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""
            If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
                flag = True
                For j = 2 To 10
                    UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
                Next j
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        If flag = False Then
            For j = 2 To 10
                UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
            Next j
        End If
    Else
        ClearForm
    End If
End Sub

Sub ClearForm()
    For j = 1 To 10
        UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: How are those images embedded in your worksheet? As links to existing image files?

Comment: Yes as hyperlinks to existing image files. Is there any other way without using hyperlinks? Please advice.

Comment: How were those pictures inserted? manually or through VBA? Are these *shapes* with the fill area linked to an image? Is the file's name available somewhere in the cell, in the shape, etc? The more you provide information about *how* those pictures were inititally inserted, the more chance you have to find a solution.

Comment: Okay. Those images in the sheet are placed using image(activex control). And i want those images to appear in image box in the userform depends on the part no typed in textbox1.

Comment: If the file names of the pics were not stored in the cells or somewhere, it's very difficult to retrieve them. And you need them because the image control does not support copy/paste.

Comment: These images are not copy and pasted. Its placed using activex image control from developer tab. We cannot retrieve the images to userform using the image names? If its difficult i can store hyperlinks to those image files in the cells replacing the images in database. But what are the changes i must do in my coding? Please advice.

Comment: These images are not copy and pasted. Its placed using activex image control from developer tab. We cannot retrieve the images to userform using the image names? If its difficult i can store hyperlinks to those image files in the cells replacing the images in database. But what are the changes i must do in my coding? Please advice.

Comment: The easiest would be to store the file's names in the cell of column L itself, under the image. If you edit your question and say that, the problem wil be reduced to retrieving the right file name and dsplaying it in the image contol of the form. In that case I have an answer. But as I told you, retrieving the linked file's name from the shape itself is extremely difficult in Excel.